# How to search data in a csv for a substring in a specific column and only extract the match with the most recent date?

Tags: php, arrays, search, fopen, fgetcsv

I'm facing a problem when trying to get the recent date for a car plate inside of a text file.

What I want to do is find the row with the most recent date value (value index [6]) containing `DPC-5345` at the start of the plate value (value index [9]).

What I have done in the following code is receive the first matching record on file, but it is not necssarily the most recent date for that plate.

```
$filename = "posicoes.txt";
$fi = fopen($filename, "r+");
$getarray = array();
$row = 1;
if (($handle = $fi) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
            $placa = mb_substr($data[9], 0, 8);
            $getarray[] = array($data[4],$data[5],$data[6],$data[8],$placa);
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
$i=1; 
while($i<=count($getarray)) {
    if ($getarray[$i][4] == 'DPC-5345') {
        break;
    } 
    $i++;
}
```

Is there anyway that can reliably return the most recent date for the searched plate?

```
"9452995","268460266","1222584",\N,"-22.905745","-47.234562","2019-02-19 14:58:32","1","5.48 Km SSO de HORTOLANDIA, SP - Brasil, 81.00 Km/h","DPC-5345-Sami"
"9452993","268460266","1223268",\N,"-5.873287","-35.220425","2019-02-19 14:58:06","1","6.59 Km NE de PARNAMIRIM, RN - Brasil, 62.00 Km/h","DCC-7567-"
"9452992","268460266","1232171",\N,"-21.832002","-47.250372","2019-02-19 14:57:34","1","0.59 Km SSO de SANTA CRUZ DAS PALMEIRAS, SP - Brasil, 0.00 Km/h","IST-0719-RODO"
"9452994","268460266","1229564",\N,"-20.262012","-42.166750","2019-02-19 14:57:17","1","13.90 Km O de MANHUACU, MG - Brasil, 88.00 Km/h","OHD-3670-SAHI"
"9452990","268460266","1225289",\N,"-18.128898","-48.568003","2019-02-19 14:57:13","1","49.92 Km E de BURITI ALEGRE, GO - Brasil, 0.00 Km/h","GHK-9324-SIRA "
"9452989","268460266","1220268",\N,"-23.625102","-48.097762","2019-02-19 14:57:01","1","5.91 Km SO de ITAPETININGA, SP - Brasil, 0.00 Km/h","DUR-6980-ROBESO"
"9452988","268460266","1235318",\N,"-17.250372","-49.241770","2019-02-19 14:56:42","1","0.20 Km S de PROFESSOR JAMIL, GO - Brasil, 56.00 Km/h","DPD-7548-JOHE"
"9452987","268460266","1222584",\N,"-22.908855","-47.213868","2019-02-19 14:56:32","1","5.66 Km S de HORTOLANDIA, SP - Brasil, 72.00 Km/h","DPC-5345-Sami"
"9452986","268460266","1223268",\N,"-5.886993","-35.232365","2019-02-19 14:56:06","1","4.58 Km NE de PARNAMIRIM, RN - Brasil, 63.00 Km/h","DCC-7567-"
"9452985","268460266","1232171",\N,"-21.831938","-47.250395","2019-02-19 14:55:34","1","0.59 Km SSO de SANTA CRUZ DAS PALMEIRAS, SP - Brasil, 0.00 Km/h","IST-0719-RODO"
"9452983","268460266","1229564",\N,"-20.246693","-42.153427","2019-02-19 14:55:17","1","12.56 Km O de MANHUACU, MG - Brasil, 12.00 Km/h","OHD-3670-SAHI"
"9452982","268460266","1225289",\N,"-18.128867","-48.567983","2019-02-19 14:55:13","1","49.92 Km E de BURITI ALEGRE, GO - Brasil, 0.00 Km/h","GHK-9324-SIRA "
"9452981","268460266","1220268",\N,"-23.625102","-48.097708","2019-02-19 14:55:01","1","5.91 Km SO de ITAPETININGA, SP - Brasil, 0.00 Km/h","DUR-6980-ROBESO"
"9452980","268460266","1235318",\N,"-17.233647","-49.234803","2019-02-19 14:54:42","1","1.82 Km NNE de PROFESSOR JAMIL, GO - Brasil, 88.00 Km/h","DPD-7548-JOHE"
"9452979","268460266","1222584",\N,"-22.898880","-47.214478","2019-02-19 14:54:32","1","4.55 Km S de HORTOLANDIA, SP - Brasil, 81.00 Km/h","DPC-5345-Sami"
"9452978","268460266","1223268",\N,"-5.890597","-35.250160","2019-02-19 14:54:06","1","3.07 Km NNE de PARNAMIRIM, RN - Brasil, 57.00 Km/h","DCC-7567-"
"9452977","268460266","1232171",\N,"-21.831958","-47.250420","2019-02-19 14:53:34","1","0.59 Km SSO de SANTA CRUZ DAS PALMEIRAS, SP - Brasil, 0.00 Km/h","IST-0719-RODO"
"9452968","268460266","1229564",\N,"-20.247340","-42.143567","2019-02-19 14:53:17","1","11.53 Km O de MANHUACU, MG - Brasil, 12.00 Km/h","OHD-3670-SAHI"
"9452966","268460266","1225289",\N,"-18.128913","-48.567978","2019-02-19 14:53:13","1","49.92 Km E de BURITI ALEGRE, GO - Brasil, 0.00 Km/h","GHK-9324-SIRA "
"9452965","268460266","1220268",\N,"-23.625155","-48.097717","2019-02-19 14:53:01","1","5.91 Km SO de ITAPETININGA, SP - Brasil, 0.00 Km/h","DUR-6980-ROBESO"
"9452976","268460266","1235318",\N,"-17.212558","-49.224920","2019-02-19 14:52:42","1","4.39 Km NNE de PROFESSOR JAMIL, GO - Brasil, 75.00 Km/h","DPD-7548-JOHE"
"9452964","268460266","1222584",\N,"-22.884487","-47.231652","2019-02-19 14:52:32","1","3.15 Km SSO de HORTOLANDIA, SP - Brasil, 73.00 Km/h","DPC-5345-Sami"
"9452962","268460266","1223268",\N,"-5.890032","-35.264475","2019-02-19 14:52:06","1","2.82 Km N de PARNAMIRIM, RN - Brasil, 40.00 Km/h","DCC-7567-"
"9452961","268460266","1232171",\N,"-21.831912","-47.250373","2019-02-19 14:51:34","1","0.58 Km SSO de SANTA CRUZ DAS PALMEIRAS, SP - Brasil, 0.00 Km/h","IST-0719-RODO"
"9452959","268460266","1229564",\N,"-20.246538","-42.153748","2019-02-19 14:51:17","1","12.60 Km O de MANHUACU, MG - Brasil, 65.00 Km/h","OHD-3670-SAHI"
"9452958","268460266","1225289",\N,"-18.128877","-48.568017","2019-02-19 14:51:13","1","49.92 Km E de BURITI ALEGRE, GO - Brasil, 0.00 Km/h","GHK-9324-SIRA "
"9452963","268460266","1220268",\N,"-23.625228","-48.097698","2019-02-19 14:51:01","1","5.92 Km SO de ITAPETININGA, SP - Brasil, 0.00 Km/h","DUR-6980-ROBESO"
"9452975","268460266","1235318",\N,"-17.197180","-49.208607","2019-02-19 14:50:42","1","6.71 Km NNE de PROFESSOR JAMIL, GO - Brasil, 86.00 Km/h","DPD-7548-JOHE"
"9452957","268460266","1222584",\N,"-22.875095","-47.253175","2019-02-19 14:50:32","1","3.88 Km SO de HORTOLANDIA, SP - Brasil, 76.00 Km/h","DPC-5345-Sami"
```

Comment: It looks like you are ignoring `$get_array[0]` in your search loop.

Comment: Are the newest lines always at the top of the file? So that for "most recent" you'd want the first occurrence it finds?

Comment: i think too, but really i have no idea how to handle that

Comment: @GregSchmidt yes it is, but in this loop its not respect the sequence ... for that i need to be sure that in loop doing that ... this code return another sequence!

Comment: side note: working with CSV might have low efficiency. Consider to import it to a database for better search performance. btw, Since the data seem not containing multibyte contents, using `mb_*()` functions are unnecessary imo.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first encountered match is the most recent...

Perform the plate search in a single iteration of the file data, then `break` when you find it.

```
$search_plate = "DPC-5345";    
$filename = "posicoes.txt";
$first_encountered_match = [];
if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r+")) === false) {
    echo "failed to access file";
} else {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
        if (mb_strpos($data[9], $search_plate) === 0) {
            first_encountered_match = $data;
            break;
        }
    }
   fclose($handle);
}
var_export(first_encountered_match);
```

Above is more efficient because of the `break` in the loop (no wasted iterations).

If you cannot rely on the ordering, then you will have to check the dates for all qualifying matches and iterate the entire set of data (without a break).

```
$search_plate = "DPC-5345";    
$filename = "posicoes.txt";
$most_recent_match = [];
if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r+")) === false) {
    echo "failed to access file";
} else {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
        if (mb_strpos($data[9], $search_plate) === 0 && (!$most_recent_match || $data[6] > $most_recent_match[6])) {
            $most_recent_match = $data;
        }
    }
   fclose($handle);
}
var_export($most_recent_match);
```

The Note in the PHP Manual @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php which speaks about efficiently searching for the existence of a substring applied to your use of `mb_substr()` as well.  Since you only mean to check if the start of the string value occurs at the start of the target element, the best tool for the job is `mb_strpos()` with a strict check for `0`.

And as @Raptor warns:

1. If you don't need multibyte string processing, you can remove the `mb_` from the `strpos()` call for improved efficiency.
2. If you are going to be performing frequent searches on this stored data and you need to write qualifying conditions on matches, the most sensible advice would be to store the data in a database.  SQL will prove to be a much cleaner, simpler, more efficient, more robust tool for your requirements.